# i am not displaying ajax table in html why?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am trying to run an application using AngularJS and Ajax. I also use a Java Controller that returns JSON. Unfortunately, html does not display the table, I cannot understand what is the matter, please help. I am just getting started with Ajax and angularJS. I am trying to output a table in Html, here are my files:

Frames.js

```
var app = angular.module('frames', []);

app.controller("FramesController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.successGetFramesCallback = function (response) {
        $scope.frameList = response.data;
        $scope.errormessage="";
    };

    $scope.errorGetFramesCallback = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        $scope.errormessage="Unable to get list of frames";
    };

    $scope.getFrames = function () {
        $http.get('/mcga/frames').then($scope.successGetFramesCallback, $scope.errorGetFramesCallback);
    };

});
```

frames.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
    <title>Schools in our university</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/frames.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="frames" ng-controller="FramesController">

<h1>Компьютерные корпуса</h1>

<div ng-controller="getFrames" ng-show="frameList.length > 0">
    <table id="frameTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><h2>Id</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Company</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Model</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Price</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Amount</h2></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="frame in frameList" id="{{frame.id}}">
            <td>{{frame.id}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.company}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.model}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.price}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my controller is written in java, it gets the list from the Database and returns it in JSON, it works fine. JSON is returned to me. Here is the code:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @GetMapping("mcga/frames")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> showAllFrames()
    {
        List<frame> frameList=service.getAllFrames();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(frameList);

    }
}
```

And my ConfigController:

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/frames").setViewName("frames");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put wrong ng-controller. It must be FramesController: Something like this

```
<div ng-controller="FramesController" ng-show="frameList.length > 0">
    <table id="frameTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><h2>Id</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Company</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Model</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Price</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Amount</h2></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="frame in frameList" id="{{frame.id}}">
            <td>{{frame.id}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.company}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.model}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.price}}</td>
            <td>{{frame.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, my error was more transparent, I incorrectly specified the path to the js file